# How do make 500 Error redirect?

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am trying to make 500, 404, etc. errors redirect. If you go to http://www.yoursite.com/934834984 it should redirect to http://www.yoursite.com/404. How do I make it do that? I tried using this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://yoursite.com/404" />
```

Keep in mind that I changed the domain to yoursite.com just for this question.

Comment: Which server are you using? Apache or something else?

Comment: @Jay I am using Host Gator. I go into the Error Pages part, and that's where I edit the 404.

Comment: host gator cPanel is **NOT** a server. It is just a software managing a server.

Comment: @RaviH goes for you too

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It is CentOS Linux according to cPanel.

Comment: then it's probably an Apache server, if it runs PHP; or a Tomcat (rarely), if it runs JSP.

Comment: Yes cPanel only runs on CentOS

Answer (score 1):

In Apache you can use `ErrorDocument`. So in your `.htaccess` file in the root of your domain you can add this to the end of the file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The files have to exist. Here is some more info as well.

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/custom-error-pages

Comment: I tried that. Here's what I added: #Error Documents

ErrorDocument 404 /hostdumpster.com/404
ErrorDocument 500 /hostdumpster.com/404

Comment: The files have to exist. Do you have file called 404 in that directory that you pointed it to? If that doens't work, Try using a file like `404.php or 404.html`

Comment: what is the exact code you're using and the name of the file? Also what are you getting instead of your custom page?

Comment: hostgator's server looks like apache server. Read apache documentation to understand how to specify custom error pages. Follow the hostgator custom-error-pages link suggested by @PanamaJack. I believe we cannot help more than this when you have limited understanding of basics of how a HTTP server and the error page serving works.

Comment: I'll just have a live chat agent do it :(

Comment: @Owen Yes that article should give you more help. One thing to note is that with 500 internal server errors you might get the default error page depending on what triggered it. If php died you should get your custom page, if not you should get the default 500 page such as a malformed htaccess file.

Comment: Can anyone like the question so I can get 5 reputation xD

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the .htacess file (with notepad) in your domain's root folder. Here are some common ones that you would add or change in the file.  Obviously change the directory and locations (the part in italics).  And don't include the numbers.  Or you can change them from your cpanel without having to mess with the .htacess file

1. ErrorDocument 400 */errors/badrequest.html*
2. ErrorDocument 401 */errors/authreqd.html*
3. ErrorDocument 403 */errors/forbid.html*
4. ErrorDocument 404 */errors/notfound.html*
5. ErrorDocument 500 */errors/server.html*

Answer (score 0):

ErrorDocument 500 /errors/server.html not work for me

show in browser HTTP ERROR 500